# Get recycler view items in spinner in another activity

Tags: android-studio

I use retrofit2 to get a category list with a model class and recyclerview adapter to get category items. In another activity I have a spinner to show category items.

How can I get category items in another activity and show in spinner?

Here is my code:

```
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Category> cats;

    public CatAdapter(Context context, List<Category> cats) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cats = cats;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cats_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.cat_title.setText(cats.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.cat_content.setText(cats.get(position).getContent());
        holder.cat_qcount.setText(cats.get(position).getQcount());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , CatPosts.class);
                intent.putExtra("catid",cats.get(position).getCatid());
                intent.putExtra("cattitle",cats.get(position).getTitle());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cats.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView cat_title,cat_content, cat_qcount;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cat_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);
            cat_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_content);
            cat_qcount =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_qcount);

        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to get items with intent because there is no click action when need to cat items.

I have an activity for sending new posts. In this activity there is a spinner that shows cat items and user select a category.

The intent in adapter sends data to CatPosts when an item is clicked. I want to get cat list when the new Post activity is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You were doing fine, now in the other activity, on your onCreate() method, do this:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    catId = intent.getStringExtra("catid");
    catTitle = intent.getStringExtra("cattitle");


    String[] x = new String[]{catId,catTitle};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterX = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.your_spinner_in_xml, x);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterX);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get question you want access to List in two activity.
If so then you have several way

**1** : Store To local Database or SharedPreferences

**2** : use `static` variables(easy way)

When you get list of category from retrofit response, store it to static List like below

```
public static List<Category> cats;
```

Then in `OnResponse()`

```
cats = response.body().getCats();
```

Now you access cats in anOther activtiy.

Comment: cats = response.body().getCats(); not correct!
i use                 if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<Category> cats =  response.body();
                    setupRecyclerView(cats);
                }

Comment: i know that. you must change it!

Comment: if you want send your code and i will fix that for you