# store categories list in static variable to use in another activity

Tags: android

i use retrofit2 and get categories list.
i use a mode class and recyclerview adapter and get categories with :

```
private void CatsRequest(){

        APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Category>> call =  apiInterface.getCategories();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {
                hidePDialog();
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<Category> cats =  response.body();
                    setupRecyclerView(cats);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Categories include title and id.
i want store this titles in a static variable and use them in another activity and show with spinner.

Comment: What's the problem? make a public static variable and set it like: MainActivity.cats = response.body();... (tip: It's a bad practice to use static variables like that)

Comment: so how can use category list in another activity?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146521/get-recylcer-view-items-in-spinner-in-another-activity